# How do I set up a default value for a text field?

Tags: views

I am trying to setup a default value according to [drupal API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.3.x) (http://take.ms/sSbow) in case if the form is empty (before use filled any data) and not successful.
In hook_form_alter() I already added the code via 
`$form['#info']['filter-field_geoaddress_proximity']['label'] = t('Distance');` and it works well. Hovewer if I try like these

```
$form['#info']['filter-field_geoaddress_proximity']['value']['#default_value'] = 21;
$form['field_geoaddress_proximity']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 21;
```

nothing happens.

This my debug info:

```
Array
(
    [operator] => field_geoaddress_proximity_op
    [value] => 2ield_geoaddress_proximity
    [label] => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup Object
        (
            [string:protected] => Distance
            [translatedMarkup:protected] => 
            [options:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [stringTranslation:protected] => 
            [arguments:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [description] => 
)
```

Could somebody help me? Doesn't matter it is in hook_form_alter() or any other hook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you setup the default value when configuring the filter -- if you've got an exposed content:type filter, then you set the default values by selecting one or more content types in the *Configure filter criterion* dialog.

I wouldn't do this via `hook_form_alter` (or similar) as you'll be fighting Views the whole way.
[image]